# Hibernate parameter typing with functions

Tags: java, hibernate, function, parameters

When using hibernate typically it can figure out the type of your parameters by looking at either the property it is against, or hibernate seems to recognise certain types by default (e.g. java.util.Date).

However I have some queries which use functions (dateadd).  In these queries using a object that has a custom type binding fails (hibernate seems to default it to BINARY when it can't figure out the type).  I have to pass in the correct hibernate "Type" against the query parameter.

This will fail

```
        Query query = session.createQuery( hql );
        query.setParameter( "now", new LocalDateTime() );
        return query.list();
```

This will work (type explicitly set)

```
        Query query = session.createQuery( hql );
        query.setParameter( "now", new LocalDateTime(), Hibernate.custom( LocalDateTimeType.class ) );
        return query.list();
```

This will also work (using java.util.Date)

```
        Query query = session.createQuery( hql );
        query.setParameter( "now", new Date() );
        return query.list();
```

Is there any way I can get Hibernate to recognise LocalDateTime as a type it can handle out of the box without having to remember to pass in the type explicitly each time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

This is apparently not possible.  There is a long-standing feature request (5 1/2 years old and counting) on this.

[Hibernate JIRA](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-26)

If you want to be complete hacker you can use some nasty reflection to do this.  I don't recommend this as it relies on inspecting the internals of both Hibernate and the implementation of UnmodifiableMap in the JDK.

```
    // HACK ALERT!!
    Field field = TypeFactory.class.getDeclaredField( "BASIC_TYPES" );
    field.setAccessible( true );
    Map basicTypes = (Map)field.get( null );

    field = basicTypes.getClass().getDeclaredField( "m" );
    field.setAccessible( true );
    Map underlyingMap = (Map)field.get( basicTypes );

    underlyingMap.put( SomeType.class.getName(), Hibernate.custom( MyCustomUserType.class ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/html/Reference_Guide/Hibernate_Types-Custom_value_types.html

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.  This isn't about custom types for properties, it is about hibernate recognising parameter types by class when it can't infer the type from the other side of the operator.  Out of the box it recognises some types but I can't see a way of adding my own type mapping that it can fall back on.